# How do you override default ggplot's aesthetics for points and lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to change the default colours for points and lines for a group of ggplots.

Of course, I can define a colour and then explicitly call it in every plot:

```
my_colour <- "firebrick"
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_line(colour = my_colour)
```

I'm trying to be lazy and avoid typing this every time.

There ought to be a theme element that I can update to change this.  I thought this might work:

```
theme_update(
  line = element_line(colour = "firebrick", size = 2, linetype = 1, lineend = "butt")
)
```

but it has no effect on the plot lines, and there isn't an equivalent for points.  I can't see any other likely elements in the [help for themes](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html).

I can force-override things by hacking the internal `GeomPath` variable, but this is bad form since we shouldn't touch internal objects.

```
gp <- ggplot2:::GeomPath
gp$default_aes <- function(.) 
{
  aes(colour = "firebrick", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = NA)
}
assignInNamespace("GeomPath", gp, "ggplot2")
```

What is the correct way to change the default aesthetics for points, lines and other geoms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, the clue was in the question: `update_geom_defaults`.

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(colour = "firebrick"))
```

I (eventually) found this via:

```
ls("package:ggplot2", pattern = "default")
```

Comment: @BrodieG Me too! It's amazing how writing down your question can lead you to the answer.